# How do I delete a directory in common lisp

Tags: directory, common-lisp

To delete a file in Common Lisp I can do:

```
(delete-file "c:\\path\\to\\file")
```

But for some reason I'm unable to find out how to delete a directory. There is no `delete-directory`, and when I pass a directory path to `delete-file` I get:

```
couldn't delete c:\path\to\folder: Unknown error
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]
```

Googling didn't help either.

I'm using Steel Banks Common Lisp on Windows, installed using Lispstick.

Answer (score 6):

`Uiop` comes with ASDF 3 and has `delete-empty-directory` and `delete-directory-tree`.

Please do use this kind of wrapper library for portability.

Answer (score 1):

Google with `common lisp delete directory` suggested me immediately [cl-fad](http://weitz.de/cl-fad/). I guess it could be useful (but I never tried it)

Comment: Yes, I saw that one, but figured a huge language like CL must be able to delete a directory without using a 3rd party library :)

Comment: It needs not.  The notion of _file_ and _directory_ are very system dependent, and were even more so at the time Common Lisp was standardized.  Therefore, the semantics of doing such things were left to the implementations.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution myself. I looked at the [source code of cl-fad](https://github.com/edicl/cl-fad/blob/master/fad.lisp) (mentioned in other answers), and saw that it basically used different extensions for the different Common Lisp implementations. Since I was using Steel Banks Common Lisp my solution was:

```
(sb-ext:delete-directory "c:\\path\\to\\folder\\")
```

For most other implementations you basically have to swap out `sb-ext` with the name of the extension package for the implementation in question.

Comment: Won't that kill compatibility you otherwise would have got using `cl-fad`?

Comment: So, instead of depending on a portability library, you now depend on a manual substitution step for installing your software for different CL implementations.  Is that really a win?